# Why does adding a DOCTYPE affect the centering of a DIV in CSS?

Tags: css, html, centering

What I was trying to do was simply center a div using CSS. and I couldn't get my head around it. It simply didn't work. I used the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
div.test {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

-->
</style>
<div class='test'>
hello
</div>
```

This didn't work on IE, it did on anything else (including my iPhone, which made it very frustrating). The div simply stayed aligned on the right.

Now for the (simple!) solution, which cost me a lot of time, and which I couldn't locate searching for the problem in a search engine. Simply add the doctype, et voila:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
```

Why did that fix it?

Comment: usually giving text-align:center to the parent div solves the problem in IE.

Comment: That isn't a recommended DTD either: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @naiquevin — That's a nasty hack with side effects and isn't needed unless you are targetting IE 5.5 and earlier. Use standards mode instead.

Comment: @david i didnt mean one should use this hack in quirks mode. I never use quirks mode but I have usually come across this prblem on IE6 even in strict mode.. particularly while centering the container or wrapper div which is immediate child of body. the only problem i think is that every thing gets center aligned after doing this and can be solved by simply giving the container text-align:left. would like to know about any other side effects you mentioned.

Comment: @patrick: Welcome to SO! Per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."  You should edit your question to be a real question, then, if your solution isn't already covered, post it as an answer.

Comment: Roger, you're right. I'll do that next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you omit the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration you get the dreaded [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), where IE tries to behave as much as possible like IE5, for compatibility reasons.

Not supporting `margin-left`/`right: auto` is one of the more prominent IE5 CSS bugs, but by no means the only one or even the worst. Quirks Mode CSS rendering is an enormous headache you should avoid at all costs. Always include a `<!DOCTYPE>` in every HTML document.

Comment: No <!doctype> declaration means a lot of bugs, bugs, bugs and introducing a lot of compatibility issues between browsers, like for example [the box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) problem. Even with a doctype, there are enough differences to break your brains with...